# Re-use websocket connection with Karate DSL

Tags: websocket, karate

With Websocket you usually dont open and close connections continously, thats why I try to use the same Websocket for all the tests in my feature file + its also required by my programming logic to do so as I currently dont support logical sessions on top of the websocket.

I tried different variations (of `call` and `callonce`) of the following but it does not work for me.

```
Feature: Notify about created fixtures

    Background:
        * def openWs = call read ('classpath:openWebsocket.js')
        * def ws = callonce openWs

    Scenario: Request a new session
        * def createSessionRequest = { 'action': 'POST', 'resource': 'sessions', 'requestId': 'df9a64de-3c22-40f8-807a-7eba5a432c95', 'version': 1 }

        * string createSessionRequest = createSessionRequest
        * eval ws.send(createSessionRequest)

        * json response = karate.listen(5000)
        * match response == { requestId: 'df9a64de-3c22-40f8-807a-7eba5a432c95', status: 201, version: 1, payload: { sessionId: '#string' } }

    Scenario: Subscribe for fixture updates
        * def subscribeFixtureRequest = { 'action': 'SUB', 'resource': 'fixtures', 'requestId': 'fa9eb7a5-d658-4f4b-bfa5-bc3bf2909cf3', 'version': 1 }

        * string subscribeFixtureRequest = subscribeFixtureRequest
        * eval ws.send(subscribeFixtureRequest)

        * json response = karate.listen(5000)
        * match response == { requestId: 'fa9eb7a5-d658-4f4b-bfa5-bc3bf2909cf3', status: 200, version: 1 }
```

It looks like it caches the websocket instance but it still closes it after the first Scenario and therefore the second one fails.

The logs look like this (with some unrelated lines deleted):

```
19:42:13.003 [main] TRACE com.intuit.karate - callonce waiting for lock: openWs
19:42:13.003 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - >> lock acquired, begin callonce: openWs
19:42:13.083 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] DEBUG c.i.k.netty.WebSocketClientHandler - websocket client connected
19:42:13.083 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - << lock released, cached callonce: openWs
19:42:13.092 [main] TRACE c.i.karate.netty.WebSocketClient - sent: {"action":"POST","resource":"sessions","requestId":"df9a64de-3c22-40f8-807a-7eba5a432c95","version":1}
19:42:13.093 [main] TRACE com.intuit.karate - entered listen wait state
19:42:13.169 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] TRACE c.i.k.netty.WebSocketClientHandler - websocket received text
19:42:13.169 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] TRACE com.intuit.karate - signal called: {"payload":{"sessionId":"ee542db6-808c-4100-b009-f9e22dce28db"},"requestId":"df9a64de-3c22-40f8-807a-7eba5a432c95","status":201,"version":1}
19:42:13.170 [main] TRACE com.intuit.karate - exit listen wait state, result: {"payload":{"sessionId":"ee542db6-808c-4100-b009-f9e22dce28db"},"requestId":"df9a64de-3c22-40f8-807a-7eba5a432c95","status":201,"version":1}
19:42:13.203 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] DEBUG c.i.k.netty.WebSocketClientHandler - websocket closing
19:42:13.204 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] DEBUG c.i.k.netty.WebSocketClientHandler - websocket client disconnected
19:42:13.249 [main] TRACE com.intuit.karate - callonce cache hit for: openWs
19:42:13.256 [main] TRACE c.i.karate.netty.WebSocketClient - sent: {"action":"SUB","resource":"fixtures","requestId":"fa9eb7a5-d658-4f4b-bfa5-bc3bf2909cf3","version":1}
19:42:13.257 [main] TRACE com.intuit.karate - entered listen wait state
19:42:18.257 [main] TRACE com.intuit.karate - exit listen wait state, result: null
```

Is there a way to control the opening and closing of the websocket myself?

EDIT: I checked the source code and its unfortunately very tightly bound to the `ScenarioExecutionUnit` and this closes it at the end of a `Scenario`. Seems there are code changes in karate necessary to support this.

Comment: yes, maybe you should just use one `Scenario`, or do consider contributing. we need to decide if we need the flexibility to keep a UI automation driver also open at a feature level. maybe a new `configure` key

Comment: I already tried some things by changing the karate code but didnt succeed yet. I will create an issue on github for this, we can discuss further things there.

Answer (score 1):

Karate will support this in the future: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/718